How to render a confirmation modal before submitting wizard form? [FilamentPHP]
I'm currently building out a wizard form with multiple steps. I want to present the user with confirmation modal before confirming the last step, and creating data in database. I managed to get the native browser confirmation popup to work, but I would really like to use the built-in filament confirmation modal.
This is what I have so far:
public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                Wizard::make([
                    Wizard\Step::make('Wihtdrawal')
                        ->icon('heroicon-o-currency-dollar')
                        ->completedIcon('heroicon-s-currency-dollar')
                        ->description('Transaction details')
                        ->columns(2)
                        ->schema([
                            Forms\Components\TextInput::make('amount')
                                ->required()
                                ->numeric()
                                ->minValue(1)
                                ->mask(RawJs::make('$money($input)'))
                                ->stripCharacters(',')
                                ->prefix('KM'),
                            Forms\Components\Select::make('store_id')
                                ->label('Office')
                                ->searchable()
                                ->required()
                                ->options(Auth::user()->currentCompany->stores()->where('status', true)->pluck('name', 'id')),
                        ])->afterValidation(function (Forms\Get $get, Forms\Set $set) {
                            $currency = Currency::where('code', 'BAM')->first();
                            $store = Store::find($get('store_id'));

                            $set('store_name', $store->name);
                            $set('withdrawal_currency', $currency->code);
                            $set('withdrawal_amount', $get('amount'));

                            $formatter = new \NumberFormatter('en', \NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
                            $set('withdrawal_amount_text', $formatter->format(str_replace(',', '', $get('amount'))));
                        }),

                    Wizard\Step::make('Overview')
                        ->icon('heroicon-o-check-circle')
                        ->completedIcon('heroicon-c-check-circle')
                        ->description('Confirm transaction')
                        ->schema([
                            Forms\Components\Fieldset::make('Deposit')
                                ->columns(3)
                                ->schema([
                                    Placeholder::make('review_store_name')
                                        ->label('Office')
                                        ->content(fn(Get $get): string => $get('store_name') ?? ''),
                                    Placeholder::make('review_withdrawal_amount')
                                        ->label('Amount')
                                        ->content(fn(Get $get): string => $get('withdrawal_amount') ?? ''),
                                    Placeholder::make('review_withdrawal_currency')
                                        ->label('Currency')
                                        ->content(fn(Get $get): string => $get('withdrawal_currency') ?? ''),
                                    Placeholder::make('review_withdrawal_amount_text')
                                        ->label('Text amount')
                                        ->content(fn(Get $get): string => $get('withdrawal_amount_text') ?? ''),
                                ])->columns(2),
                        ]),
                ])
                    ->skippable(false)
                    ->columnSpanFull()
                    ->submitAction(new HtmlString(Blade::render(<<<BLADE
                            <x-filament::button
                                type="button"
                                size="sm"
                                wire:confirm="Are you sure you want to create this withdrawal?"
                                wire:click="create"
                            >
                                Confirm
                            </x-filament::button>
                        BLADE)))
            ]);
    }

As you can see, I added confirmation popup here:
->submitAction(new HtmlString(Blade::render(<<<BLADE
    <x-filament::button
        type="button"
        size="sm"
        wire:confirm="Are you sure you want to create this withdrawal?"
        wire:click="create"
    >
        Confirm
    </x-filament::button>
BLADE)))

And this is how it looks like:

And I want it to be like this:

I've tried including a custom action in the ->submitAction() method, but I couldn't get it to work:
use Filament\Actions\Action;
->submitAction(Action::make('confirm')->requiresConfirmation())

This way, the button shows up, but when clicking it, nothing happens:

Any help is appreciated.

In case if anyone needs a similar solution to this, here's how I did it. Basically, I created my own custom submit action button, instead of the original one that comes with the wizard:
Forms\Components\Actions\Action::make('submit')
   ->requiresConfirmation()
   ->modalIcon('heroicon-s-arrow-down-tray')
   ->modalDescription('Are you sure you want to do this?')
   ->action(function (Action $action) use($form){
      //submit the form here/
   });


add this into your CreateResource class:
protected function getCreateFormAction(): Action
{
  return parent::getCreateFormAction()
    ->submit(form: null) // set the form data to null, prevent save process
    ->requiresConfirmation()
    ->action(function() {
        $this->closeActionModal(); // Close btn
        $this->create();  // process the create method
    }
}


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
